# Blender Python bpy build with Python 3.8

Tags: python

I would like to try Blender's bpy module with FreeCAD.
Thing is FreeCAD is currently built with Python 3.8, when I went to build bpy it wants Python3.9. Is it possible to build bpy with Python 3.8?

I built with 3.9 and copied bpy.so to a location that FreeCAD would find but when I try
import bpy in FreeCAD python console, FreeCAD crashes.

Comment: From https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

Testing
This allows 'bpy' to be imported from python or other applications/IDE's which embed python, eg:

python -c "import bpy; bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)"
Or:

python -c "import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath='my.blend')" 
This runs in background mode and has similar restrictions to running a script:

blender --background --python test.py

Comment: Yes. Download any python source tarball > 3.6 (or whatever the min is) , and build blender against it.  Was building against 3.92, ... was shocked to DL an official version and see it was 3.77 Found cmake-gui a very handy tool tool for configuring a build.  @ZargulTheWizard `bpy` as a python module is. Prob the best way to get auto-completion etc working in IDEs. Suggest removing comment.  (_IMO would love to see it distributed_)